# Как из текста сделать переменную в Javascript

Tags: javascript, строки, переменные, variable

Недавно возникла потребность вызвать функцию (условно обозначим функцию foo()) от повторяющихся переменных (например str1, str2, str3, ... , str93).
И чтобы не писать 93 вывода в консоль, я решил передавать в функцию параметры в виде строки из частички arr и итератора i

```
// Тут объявляем эти 93 строки

let str1 = "ahfsGv s@!uuyyt"
let str2 = "kjl;sad543aVnn"
let str3 ="j hdgf "
...
let str93 = "aP)($53"

function foo(str) {
  // Тут манипуляции с принимаемой строкой, но они нам не важны
}

for (let i = 0; i < 93; i++;) {
  // Я даже завёл отдельную переменную чтобы вынести этот шаблон параметра
  let param = `arr${i}`
  // И здесь появилась проблема
  console.log(foo(param))
}
```

*Как мне передать в функцию параметр, который сейчас в виде строки, или как перевести строку в готовую переменную для последующей её передачи в функции?*

**На сегодня само задание по манипуляции с 93-мя строками выполнено, но другим способом,** а я бы, всё-таки, хотел узнать как сделать из строки полноценную переменную, которую можно было бы передать в мою(да и не только) функцию. Заранее благодарю за ответ!!!

Comment: У вас переменные имеют названия `str1, str2,`, а шаблон вы создаете `arr1, arr2` - где логика?

Comment: Хе-хе, видимо очепятался, но это не проблема, то есть я создавал шаблон `str${i}`

Answer (score 1):

```
// Тут объявляем 1 массив из 93 строк

let arr = [
"ahfsGv s@!uuyyt",
"kjl;sad543aVnn",
"j hdgf ",
...
"aP)($53"
];

function foo(str) {
  // Тут манипуляции с принимаемой строкой, но они нам не важны
}

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++;) {
  // Я даже завёл отдельную переменную чтобы вынести этот шаблон параметра
  let param = arr[i];
  // И здесь проблем нет
  console.log(foo(param))
}
```

Касаемо ответа на ваш вопрос:

```js
let s = 'name';
let name = 'bar';
console.log(eval(s));
```

Но, НИКОГДА так НЕ делайте.

Comment: Супер, спасибо. Буду знать о таком, но НИКОГДА не буду применять)

Comment: @МирославТолошный, почитайте подробнее здесь https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Answer (score 1):

Предложу другой вариант без eval

Вариант который не работает

```js
console.log(str1);
console.log(str2);
console.log(str3);
//... мне лень
console.log(str92);
```

Вариант который работает

```js
//объявляем переменные str1 str2 
for(let i = 1; i < 93; i++){
  window["str" + i] = "some text "  + i * i;
}


console.log(str1);
console.log(str2);
console.log(str3);
//... мне лень
console.log(str92);
```

ну и продолжая усложнять можно придумать такое, и передать в параметры какого нибудь метода

```js
//объявляем переменные str0 str1 
window["fibonacci" + 0] = 0n;
window["fibonacci" + 1] = 1n;

for(let i = 2; i < 93; i++){
  window["fibonacci" + i] = window["fibonacci" + (i - 1)] + window["fibonacci" + (i - 2)];
}

print(fibonacci0);
print(fibonacci1);
print(fibonacci2);
print(fibonacci3);
//... мне лень
print(fibonacci90);
print(fibonacci91);
print(fibonacci92);


function print(arg){
  console.log(arg.toString())
}
```